# Devise validation constantly failing on sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Making a simple Ruby on Rails app as practise that requires a user to sign up.

Everything works well until I implement regex validation on a 'profile_name' field

Here's my 'user' model:

```
validates :profile_name, presence: true,
                           uniqueness: true,
                           format: {
                            with: /^a-zA-Z0-9_-$/,
                            message: 'Must be formatted correctly.'
                           }
```

And yet the profile name 'jon' simply refuses to pass. Where could this error be coming from, other than my 'user' model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add brackets around the ranges so that the regex matches "any of the range" rather than "all of the range in order". Put a + on the end to allow it to match anything in the range more than once.
You also need to change your beginning and ending of lines to beginning and ending of strings!

```
validates :profile_name, presence: true,
                         uniqueness: true,
                         format: {
                           with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\z/,
                           message: 'Must be formatted correctly.'
                         }
```

Details:

```
\A # Beginning of a string (not a line!)
\z # End of a string
[...] # match anything within the brackets
+ # match the preceding element one or more times
```

Really useful resource for generating and checking regex: http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws

Answer (score 1):

Try like this , It is working fine

```
 validates :name, presence: true,
                               uniqueness: true,
                               format: {
                                with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_-$]+\z/,
                                message: 'Must be formatted correctly.'
                               }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your regular expression in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) with the 'jon'. There is no matching.

I am not optimized regular expression coder. But still the below regular expression works.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/
```

So try

```
 validates :name, presence: true,
                           uniqueness: true,
                           format: {
                            with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/,
                            message: 'Must be formatted correctly.'
                           }
```